# How do I do something at the end of a page animation from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I am using the August 2011 SilverlighT Toolkit to do a page animation. I have defined the animation in a Style that I apply to the page.

There is a UI element that I only want displayed once the animation has finished. I thought I could just set its IsVisible property to true, but when? Is there an event that I can subscribe to or something? How do I access the transition from the style?

Answer (score 0):

By saying when the animation has finished, do you mean when you page is loaded? You could use the `Loaded` event on the page. The users can access the ui elements only when the page are loaded. There is also `onNavigatedTo` event.

Comment: I mean somewhat after the page is loaded. I think the page is loaded before the page transition animation is finished.